# How to configure PHP on http-server

Tags: php, angularjs, apache

I'm doing a project that involves using a server to host files on the web. I'm very new to web hosting technologies and I found an angular tutorial that used a very simple server called http-server and with this tutorial I was able to get a site hosted to localhost. Getting something hosted using the tutorial required to know very little about how each individual step was working. I want to use PHP but also being new to that, I know that it's server side and I need the server to have PHP installed but I have no idea how or if it's possible given this tool.

I'm not sure if have to move to a larger scale web server with php installed by default like Apache, but I'd prefer to keep it simpler if possible. Here's a link to the tutorial and server utility if that helps at all

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00

https://github.com/indexzero/http-server

Comment: cant you just install a WAMP\LAMP stack? ?

Comment: No idea what that is, but I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to publish anything "on the web", there's really no need to create a webserver on your own. Any provider you choose will have everything you need preinstalled for very little money, usually in the form of a LAMP stack. (Linux/Apache/Mysql/PHP). The DIY webserver you tested is a security risk at best if you're online with it. And simple as it may seem, the AngularJS server is surely more trouble than just using a pre-installed LAMP, especially when you think about maintenance. If you do not plan to use a commercial webhosting provider, tell us what your platform is, and somebody will be able to point you in the right deirection with a LAMP or WAMP install. It's not that difficult, really.